# Convert list of list of object to diferents widgets nested

Tags: flutter, dart

i have a List of List of one type,

```
    class MenuModel {
        String title = "";
        String? route;
        List<MenuModel>? menues;
    
        MenuModel(this.title, this.route, this.menues);
    }
    
    List<MenuModel> menu = [
        MenuModel("Clientes", null, [
          MenuModel("Consulta", ClientsInquiry.route, null),
          MenuModel("Cuenta Corriente", ClientsCheckingAccount.route, [
            MenuModel("Option 1", "route", null),
            MenuModel("Option 2", "route", [
              MenuModel("Option 1", "route", null),
              MenuModel("Option 1", "route", null),
            ]),
            MenuModel("Option 3", "route", null),
          ]),
          MenuModel("Estado de Cuenta", ClientsAccountStatus.route, null),
          MenuModel("Documentos", ClientsDocuments.route, null),
        ]),
      ];
    ];
```

I use this struct to define a Menu.

Where Title 1 contains Option 1 and Sub Menu 1 and
Sub Menu 1 contains Option 1, Option 2 and Sub Sub Menu 1 and
Sub Sub Menu contains Option 1.

Title 1 is a ExpansionTile
and Option 1 is a ListTile.

I try to create a algorithm that create a Flutter code required to create this Structure.

Help please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I solve the problem with this functions

```
static Widget getMenu(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> widgetMenu = [];

    for (var menu in _menu) {
      widgetMenu.add(getSubOptions(context, menu));
    }

    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: widgetMenu,
    );
  }

  static Widget getSubOptions(BuildContext context, MenuModel menu) {
    if(menu.menues == null || menu.menues!.isEmpty){
      return ListTile(
          title: Text(menu.title),
          onTap: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, menu.route!),
        );
    } else {
      List<Widget> subOptions = [];

      for (var element in menu.menues!) {
        subOptions.add(getSubOptions(context, element));
      }

      return ExpansionTile(
        title: Text(menu.title),
        children: subOptions,
      );
    }
  }
```